# The page at 'https://example.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest Endpoint

Tags: javascript, html, http, https

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.timedevs.xyz/application/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://emustore4ios/aceradio/es4iosradio.php'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: why did someone vote this down i actually need help!!!

Answer (score 1):

From an https webpage you should only do https (secure) requests.

On your page something make an http (insecure) request. The browser block it for security reasons.

Find what does that request and modify it to call the https endpoint instead if possible.

Comment: I know what does that request and it is something i cannot control it is a user based localStorage radio system which uses http or https to

Comment: It's the user who choose the url ? Then explain to the user that he can only use https urls.

Comment: Well then that basically ruins the ideas of a user based and hosted radio station app

Comment: Two solutions: ask your users to get a domain and a certificate, or proxy their content.

Comment: Ok i like the second option because i dont want my users to pay for anything so how do i proxy the content?